# How to query the active nominators of X validator in past eras?

Tags: staking

I need to be able to query the addresses of the active nominators of a validator in a past era (eg 695).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should query the `ErasStakers` storage item in the Staking Pallet:

```rust
/// Exposure of validator at era.
///
/// This is keyed first by the era index to allow bulk deletion and then the stash account.
///
/// Is it removed after `HISTORY_DEPTH` eras.
/// If stakers hasn't been set or has been removed then empty exposure is returned.
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn eras_stakers)]
pub type ErasStakers<T: Config> = StorageDoubleMap<
    _,
    Twox64Concat,
    EraIndex,
    Twox64Concat,
    T::AccountId,
    Exposure<T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>>,
    ValueQuery,
>;
```

The `Exposure` struct contains the vector of nominators in `other`:

```rust
/// A snapshot of the stake backing a single validator in the system.
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
pub struct Exposure<AccountId, Balance: HasCompact> {
    /// The total balance backing this validator.
    #[codec(compact)]
    pub total: Balance,
    /// The validator's own stash that is exposed.
    #[codec(compact)]
    pub own: Balance,
    /// The portions of nominators stashes that are exposed.
    pub others: Vec<IndividualExposure<AccountId, Balance>>,
}
```

If you query is beyond the history of this storage item on the current block, you will simply need to query the storage in a past block on an archive node.

Comment: Thanks Shawn 